# changing membership type from fixed to rolling. What happens to existing memberships?

Tags: civimember

Our organization is relatively new, but we wish to change from fixed annual memberships to rolling.  I see it is easy to change that in the membership type, but wonder about how to make the needed changes to the existing membership since/start/end dates.

Currently, all memberships start on 1/1/2020, and end on 12/31/2020, but the memberships have a "member since" date that is the ACTUAL day they became members.  (All those dates are within 2020 also, since we are a new organization.)

What I would like, I believe, is to copy the "member since" date into the "Membership Start" date field, overwriting the January 1 date, and set the "end date" == the Start date + 1 year (overwriting 12/31/2020).  Is there likely to be any automatic way to do that as a global update?  (If I must do it manually, I can; there are under 200 memberships.)

Are there any "gotchas" involved in this?  Would I be wiser to create a new Membership type rather than change the existing one?  Should I edit the fields BEFORE I change the membership type rather than after?

If it matters, I am using CiviCRM 5.29.0 on Wordpress 5.5.1.  Thanks!

Comment: I think you are on the right track but would test first of course. Try setting up a Profile with your Membership date fields and see if you can modify that way. will be much quicker. Not sure if without a 'resave' the End Date would update itself, so you may need to change that too. Or do each manually. Or if you have access to the db and know what you are doing you could do an SQL query to make the changes but would need to change End Date too.